# Switch to Map/Enum or something else

Tags: java, dictionary, enums, switch-statement

I like to know 2 things:

1. Is it worth to convert from switch to something
2. How this will look like in my case? The biggest problem is for me "case ID_BOTH:"

Piece of my cake:

```
    public void init( int boxID ) {

    initComponentText();

    switch ( boxID ) {

        case ID_IMAGE:
            initComponentImg();
            break;

        case ID_BOOL:
            initComponentBool();
            break;

        case ID_BOTH:
            initComponentBool();
            initComponentImg();
            break;
    }
}

private void initComponentImg() {
    img = new ComponentImg( switchComponent );
}

private void initComponentBool() {
    bool = new ComponentBool( switchComponent );
}

private void initComponentText() {
    text = new ComponentText( switchComponent );
}
```

Thanks for help and tips.

Comment: *How this will look like in my case?* How **what** will look in your case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [bitwise](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) `AND` operator instead

```
public void init( int boxID ) {
  initComponentText();

  if ((boxID & ID_IMAGE) == ID_IMAGE) initComponentImg();
  if ((boxID & ID_BOOL) == ID_BOOL) initComponentBool();
}
```

Assuming that

```
int ID_IMAGE = 1;
int ID_BOOL = 2;
int ID_BOTH = 3;
```

See [DEMO](http://ideone.com/QGBTzd)

Answer (score 3):

I think if condition will be more helpful to reduce the code complexity;

```
    if(ID_IMAGE==boxID||ID_BOTH==boxID)
        initComponentImg();
    if(ID_BOOL==boxID||ID_BOTH==boxID)
        initComponentBool();
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you let `ID_BOTH` be the bitwise-OR of `ID_BOOL` and `ID_IMAGE`, and your individual "types" don't have overlapping binary values (e.g. powers of 2), you can bitwise-AND `boxId` to check for individuality. Using this method you could then keep bitwise-OR'ing all your types together.

```
int ID_NONE = 0
int ID_BOOL = 1;
int ID_IMAGE = 2;
int ID_TEXT = 4;

int ID_BOOL_IMG = ID_BOOL | ID_IMAGE; // 3
int ID_BOOL_TEXT = ID_BOOL | ID_TEXT; // 5
int ID_BOOL_ALL = ID_BOOL | ID_IMAGE | ID_TEXT; // 7

if ((boxId & ID_BOOL) == ID_BOOL) {
    initComponentBool(); // runs for boxId = 1, 3, 7
}
if ((boxId & ID_IMAGE) == ID_IMAGE) {
    initComponentImg(); // runs for boxId = 2, 3, 7
}
if ((boxId & ID_TEXT) == ID_TEXT) {
   initComponentText(); // runs for boxId = 4, 5, 7
}
```

Comment: What if boxID = ID_BOTH ??

Comment: This doesn't handle ID_BOTH. Are you thinking of changing the boxID to a bitwise-OR value?

Comment: Guess you're right :) I was thinking logically rather than programatically.

Comment: Answer updated with bitwise. Thanks for the thought, @AndyThomas

Comment: @Shivam - adding `else if` will cause only the first matching condition to be entered.